# XPath как выделять ссылки (<a>) с атрибутом?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Есть страница, где нужно выделить все ссылки `<a>` с классом `'foo'`.
Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$x( '//a[$class="foo"]' )
```

Но в ответе я получаю ->

```
[] (пустой массив)
```

Будьте добры подскажите в чем проблема.
Команду ввожу в консоли Chrome.

Comment: `$` на `@` замените

Comment: Спасибо большое